# UnsatisfiedDependencyException, Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-repositories

when I'm trying to start the application I get the following message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Acasa\0 SDA\0 Proiecte
> practice\attentive2details\target\classes\com\example\attentive2details\Service\ProductServiceImpl.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in
> com.example.attentive2details.repositories.ProductRepository defined
> in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List
> com.example.attentive2details.repositories.ProductRepository.findByNameStartingWith(java.util.List)!
> No property name found for type Produs!

This is happening since I have added a new method `List<Produs> findByNameStartingWith(List<Produs> string)` into the `ProductRepository`.

The application code is:

```
@Data
@Table
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor


public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String produs;
    @Column
    private Float calories;
}



@Repository

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

   List<Product> findByNameStartingWith(List<Product> string);
 
}


public interface ProductService {

    List<Product> findByNameStartingWith(List<Product> string);
    
}


@Service

public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Product> findByNameStartingWith(List<Product> string) {
        return productRepository.findByNameStartingWith(string);
    }
}


@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController

public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }


    @GetMapping("findProductbyNameStartingWith/produs")
    @Query("FROM Product p WHERE p.produs LIKE %:name%")
    public List<Product> findProductsbyNameStartingWith(@Param("name") String beginswith) {
        List<Product> allproducts = new ArrayList<>( productService.findAll());
        List<Product> productsListBeginWith = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Product product : allproducts) {
            if(product.getProdus().startsWith(String.valueOf(beginswith))){
                productsListBeginWith.add(product);
            }
        }
        return productService.findByNameStartingWith(productsListBeginWith);
    }
}
```

[the application structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgFtn.png)

Answer (score 1):

As your log mention

> com.example.attentive2details.repositories.ProductRepository.findByNameStartingWith(java.util.List)!
> No property name found for type Produs!

You wrote `findByNameStartingWith` but you don't have `name` field in your model. Jpa couldn't find this property in your entity class. You should put the `name` property in your model or change the query to another field for example `findByProdusStartingWith` or `findByCaloriesStartingWith`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Faramarz Afzali answer (which is actually correct), please note that the following `@Query` have no effect:

```java
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    (...)

    @GetMapping("findProductbyNameStartingWith/produs")
    @Query("FROM Product p WHERE p.produs LIKE %:name%")
    public List<Product> findProductsbyNameStartingWith(@Param("name") String beginswith)
    
    (...)
}
```

`@Query` must be used in Repository methods, not on a Controller or Service.